# How to make the "today" button appear in DevExpress.DateEdit?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress-windows-ui

I am using DevExpress.DateEdit control in WinForms version number 12.1.
How can i make the today button appear in this and also how can i navigate month wise. For now i have navigation year wise.

I am using .net 4.0 Winforms, DevExpress.DateEdit 12.1

Answer (score 0):

VistaEditTime = True and VistaDisplayMode = false properties helped me to achieve this.